# python 2.7 read file with big line

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, sequence, fasta

I have a fasta file and I want to print only the sequence

```
f = open ("NC_007970.fas",'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

it prints only the first line `> NC_007970`

I think the problem is from the fasta file itself it's composed of first line with '>', and the second line is the sequence and no new lines in the sequence itself and its length is about 19000 character

```
> NC_007970
GTTATTGTAGCTTACACTAAAGCATGGCACTGAAGTTGCCAAGATGGGTAATCAAAATACCCCAAAAACACAAAGATTTGGTCCTAACCTTACTGTTACTTTTTGCTAAAATTACACATGCAAGTATCAGCATACCAGTGAAAACACCCTAGCAATCCTATTAGACAAAGGAGCCGGTATCAGGCACACCATGATAGCCCAAGACACCTAGCTTTGCCACACCCCCAAGGGCATTCAGCAGTGATAAAAATTAAGCAATAAGCGCAAGCTCGACTTAATTATAGCAAACATAGAGCTGGCCAATCTCGTGCCAGCCGCCGCGGTTATACAAGAAGCCCAAACTAACAGACAACCGGCGTAAAATGTGGCTAAAAATTTATCTACAAAATTAAGGCGAACCTACAACTTAACTGTTATACGCAAGTACACATTAATACATTATGAAAATAACCTTAACACAATAGAACTATTTGAACCCACTATCGCTAAGGCACAAACTGGGATTAGATACCCCACTATGCTCAGCCCTAAACTTAGATATTTACTTACAATAATATCCGCCAGAGAACTACGAGCCCAAACGCTTAAAACTCTAAAGACTTGGCGGTACCTCAACCTCCTAGAGGAGCCTGTTCTATAATCGATAATCCACGATCTACCTCACCATCCCTTGTCAATTCAGCCTATATACCACCGTCATTAGCTTACCCTGTGAAGGGTACCAAGTAAGCAAAATAACCTAAACAACTAGCAAGTCAGGTCAAGGTGTAGCTAACTGAGATGGAAGAAATGGGCTACATTTTCTTTATTAGAAATCACTTAACAGAAAGGACCATGAAATAAGTCCCATAAGTAGGATTTAGCAGTAAACTGGGAACAGAGAGCCCAATTTAAGTCGGTCCTGAGGTGCGCACACACCGCCCGTCACCCTCCTCAAATAATCCTTAAGCATAGATAAACCACAACAAACAAATAGATGAGGCAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAAGTGTACCGGAAGGTGTACTTGGAACATCAAAATATAGCTTATCAAAAGCACTCAGCTTACACCTGAAAGTTGTCCATTAAAATCGGATTATTTTGAGCAACTACCTAGCCCAACTAATAAATATAAAACCCAACAAACAAATTATCCTACCAATAAATCAACTAAAACATTTTACCATCATAGTATAGGAGATAGAAAAGATAATTGGAGCTATAAAGACAGTACCGCGAGGGAAAGATGAAAAACATGAAACACTCACCAAGCCAGAAAAAGCAAAGATTAACTCTTGTACCTTTTGCATCATGATTTAGCCAGTACATCCAAGCAAAGAGAACTAAAGTCTGAACTCCCGAAACCAAATGAGCTACTTAAAGGTAGCCTATACCACCATGGGCTAAATCCGTCTCTGTGGCAAAAGAGTGGAGAAACCTTTAAGTAGAGGTGAAAAGCCTAACGAACCTGGTGATAGCTGGTTGCTCAACAAAAGAATATCAGTTCAACCTTAAACCTCCTAACCTAACAACTTTGAAGTAATAGAAGAGAAGTTTAAGATATATTCAACAGGGGTACAGCCCTGTTGAAAAAGGGTACAACCTAAAATGCAGGACAAAACATCAAAGCAAGACCACAGTAGGCCTTAAAGCAGCCATCTCCAAAGAAAGCGTCAAAGCTCACTACAATTAATATCAACACAATTTTTTTCCCCTAAACAACATTGAGCTATTCTATCACCATAGAAGAACTAATGCTAAAATGAGTAACAAGAAGACGAAACTTCTCTTCCGCGCCAACTTAAATCATAATAGATAAACTACTGATTATTACAACCAATATTATAAGATCAACAGTACTTAATACACCATATAAACCCAACTGTTAACCCAACACAGGAGCGCACACAAGAAAGATTAAAATTTGTAAAAGGAACTAGGCAAACATTGAGCTCGACTGTTTACCAAAAACATAGCCCCTAGCAACAATAAGTATTAGGGGTAATGCCTGCCCAGTGACACTGTTCAACGGCCGCGGTATCCTAACCGTGCAAAGGTAGCGTAATCACTTGTCTTTTAAATAAGGACTAGAATGAACGGCTAAACGAGGTTCTACCTGTCTCTTACAAATAATCAGTGAAATTGGTCTTCCAGTGCAAAACCTGGAATAAAAATATAAGACGAGAAGACCCTGTGGAACTTTAAATACAAATCAATCTATTATTCATACCCACCCACGATGGTTTATCACCAATTAGCACATTGATCCATATTTTCGGTTGGGATGACCTCAGAGTAAAATTAAACCTCTGAACAAAGAACACACCTCCAAACCTAGACCCACCATTCAAAGTGCTTACAGCAAAATGATCCAATACACTTGATCAACGAACCAAGCTACCCCAGGGATAACAGCGCAATCCTATCCTAGAGTCCCTATCGACGATAGGGTTTACGACCTCGATGTTGGATCAGGACATCCTAATGGTGTAACCGCTATCAAGGGTTCGTTTGTTCAACGATTAATAGTCCTACGTGATCTGAGTTCAGACCGGAGTAATCCAGGTCGGTTTCTATCTATAAATGGGCTTTTTCTAGTACGAAAGGACCGAAAAGACAAGGCCTATTTTTAAAAACAAGCCTTACCTTATATTAGTGAAAGCAACTTAACTAATAATAAGGACAAACCATTTAACCCTAAAAAGGGGTTATTGAGGTGGCAGAGCCTGGTACAAAAGGCCTAAGCCCTTTACTCAGGGGTTCAAATCCCCTCCCCAATAATGAAAGCCCTATTATCAAACCTAATATCCCCACTTATATATATAATCCCAGTCTTAATTGCTGTAGCTTTCTTTACCTTAATTGAACGGAAAACTTTGGGATACATACAACTCCGAAAAGGCCCAAACATCGTAGGACCATGTGGACTTTTACAACCTGTAGCTGATGGTGTAAAACTATTTATTAAGGAACCAGTGTACCCATCAAACTCATCAACTATACTATTTACACTATCACCAATCCTAGCTCTACTACTATCTTTATCAGTCTGACTTCCACTGCCTCTACCATTTCCACTAGCCGACTTAAACCTAGGCCTCCTATTCCTAATTTCAATATCCAGCTTCATAGTTTACTCCATCTTATGATCTGGCTGAGCTTCAAACTCCAAGTACGCCTTAGTAGGGGCACTCCGGGCAGTAGCCCAAACTATCTCATACGAAGTAACCCTAGGAATCATCCTACTCTCCCTAATCCTATTCTCAGGCGGATTCAACATACAAACATTTATAACAACGCAGGAACCTGCGTACCTGATATTCTCATCCTGACCTTTAATAATAATATGGTATATCTCCACATTAGCAGAAACAAATCGAGCACCATTCGACCTTTCCGAAGGAGAATCTGAACTCGTATCAGGGTTTAACGTTGAATACGCCGCCGGCCCATTCGCCCTATTCTTCCTAGCAGAGTACGCTAATATTCTGATAATAAACACCCTCACCACTATCCTATTCCTGAATCCATCCCATATTAACAACACCCCCGAACTATTTTCATTATCATTAGTATCAAAAATAATACTACTCTCAGTAGGATTCCTATGAATCCGCGCCTCATACCCGCGATTCCGATATGACCAGTTAATACACTTATTATGAAAAAACTTCCTCCCTATTACCTTAGCAATGTGCCTCTGACATATATCTATGCCAACTGCCTTCTCGGGGCTACCACCGATGTTATAGGATACGTGCCTGAAATTAAAGGATCACCTTGATAAGGTGAATCATAGAGGCTAAACCCTCTCGTCTCCCTAAAAGAAAGCACCTTTACCTATAAATAACAAAATCCTATACCTGTATATTACTGTACTGAATTCATAAATTACACTACACACAATATTATCTAACCACAAATTAACACTCCATAAACCACTACATTAAAAATACAATATAGTACTATAACAGCATAACCCTTTATAAAATACCCTACAACCCATTTATAACATATATTATGAAATAAACTACCCCTTATTAAAATTACTAACAACTTCTCATAACAAACTACACAAAATCAAGCCAATATATCTTAATTTCTCGACTACAAACAATTTACCAACGTATTATCCCGTTACTTCCATAAATACACAATCCTTTTACCTAACAAACAAATTAAAACCAATTACCCTAACAGCAAAAAACACCAATATTCATCAAAAACCCCAACATATCTGAAAAATAAACTCCCTATTGTACTATTATAGGACCTAAAATACCCAAAACCCCTTTAGGTCAATATAGTTTAAAACAAACATTAGACTGTGATTCTAAAAATAGGAGTGTAAATCCCCTTATAGACCAAGAGAGATCCAACAGTAAGAACTGCTAATTCTTATACCTGAGACTAACACCTCAGCTCCCTTACTTTTAAAGGATAGAAGTAATCCACTGGTTTTAGGAACCATAAACCCTTGGTGCAACTCCAAGTAAAAGAACATGCCAACACCCCCACTGTTAGCCTTAACACATTTTATGACCCTAGCTATCCTGCTAGTTCCACTAGTAATCTCTATACTCACTACAAAAGTGTGAATTATTGAAAAGACAAAAACATCCGTGAAAACAGCGTTTTTTACCTCCATACTATCATTTCTCCTCTTTAAAGCTGAGTCCACCCCTTTCATAGTAATAGACTATAACCTATTAAGCACATCAACCTTCTATGTAAAGCTTAACTTTAAATTTGACCTATACTCCATACTATTTACACCAGTTGCCTTATACGTCTCATGATGTATTTTAGAGTTTTCACAATGATACATAGACAAAGACCCCTATCCCTCAAAATTCGCCAAATACCTACTAACCTTCATTATAGCTATAATAATCCTAGTATCAGCTAATAACCTACTCCTATTTTTTATTGGTTGGGAGGGGGTAGGAATCCTATCCTTCCTCCTAATCGCATGATGGCGAAACCGACCAAACACGAATACATCAGCCCTACAAGCTATTATCTACAACCGCATAGGAGACATCGGACTAATCTTATGTCTAGCATGACTAACAACACGCCTAAACACATTAGCACTCCAAAAAATCTTCACGTGTAATGACTTCATCACACTCCTACCATTACTAGGCCTTATCCTAGCTGCAATAGGCAAATCAGCCCAATTCGGCCTCCACCCCTGATTACCAGCAGCTATGGAAGGTCCAACCCCAGTCTCAGCGTTACTACACTCAAGTACTATGGTGGTCGCTGGCATTTTCCTACTAATCCGCATACACCCCGTATTAACCCTCAATAAATATGCTCTTTCAGCATGCCTGCTATTGGGAGCAATTACCTCATTAGTGGCAGCCTTTTGCGCTCTAACCCAAAATGATATTAAAAAAATCATTGCCTTCTCCACATCAAGCCAACTTGGCTTTATAATAGTAACCGTGGGCCTAGACCAACCACAACTAGCCTTCCTCCATCTCTCATTACACGCCTTCTTTAAAGCCATATTATTTCTATGCTCAGGTTCCATTATTCATAACCTTAATAACGAACAAGACATTCGAAAAATAGGCGGATTACATAAATGTTTACCCATCACCTCTGCATGCTTAACCATCGGCAGCATAGCGCTTGCAGGCACGCCATTCCTAACTGGATTCTACTCTAAAGATATTATTATCGAAACCATGACCACATCACATCTAAATGCTTTTGCCCTACTCATTACACTAATCGCAACCTCATTCACTGTGGTATACAGCCTGCGGATTACAATATTTGTACAAACAGGACAACCCCAACACATATCCATACTACTATTAGATGAATACAACCCGCTAGTTATCAACCCTATCATCCGCCTAGCTACAGGCAGCATTGCTGCCGGATTAATTATTTCAATAAACATTACACCGCTAGAAACCCCACCAATAACCATACCAACATACATTAAAACCGTAACATTAATGGTAGTAGCCCTAAGCCTCCTAATAGCCCTAAAACTAGCTACTATAACCAATAAAATACCCCCAAAATCATCCCACACCCATAACTTTTCCAACTCACTAATGTACTTTAATACCATAATTCACCGCTCAACACCAATAATTACTTCAACCATTAGTGAAAAATACTCAACCCGAATAATAGACTCAACCTGACAAGAAAAAATAGGCCCAAAAAAACTAGCTGAGTCACAAGTACTGCCTACTAAAACAACCTCTTCATTGCAAAAAGGCCTCATTAAAATTTATTTAACCTCATTTATCCTATCCGTCCTACTTCTTATTTACTTATTTGACTAATATACAAAACTAGTAAAATAAACATTACCCGCCGGATGTAATACGCTAAAAGGATATTACCCAAGATCTTAAAACCACTTCTCTAACTGCTAGGAACCAAAACCTTTTTACCCAAGTACCCACTATTTTTTAACCGCGCCTCACCATACATTCTAGTAGCTATCAACAAAGCATTGGTCTTGTAAACCAAAGACTGAAGACTATAATCTTCCTAGAATAATCAAAAGAGAAGGACTTAAACCTCCATTCCCGGCCCCCAAAACCGAAATCTTTTATTAAACTATCTTTTGACACCCCCCCCCCCCCCGATGGGCATGCTCATCGAATTTTGCCTAAATATAGGACAATTTACACCCTATGTACGTCGTGCATACTTTTATTTACCCCTAGCATATATTTAGTAATATCCCTGCTTAATCTTACATAAAAGTATATTCCCCATAATCTATCCAGATAACAGTAATTTAATGGTTTAAGGACATAATATTCTATAGTGCTTTACAACATGACTATTGTCACAGTATTGGGTTATTTCCTAATCTACCTAATCACGAGAGATAAGCAACCCTTGTTTGTAAGATACAACGTTACCAGTTTCAGGCCCATATTCATGATGGCGTACATAACTGATCTATTCTGGCCACTGGCTGTTTTTTCAGGCACATGTTATCCACTAAGTTCATTCGTTCCTCTTTAAAAGGCCTCTGGTTAAATGAGTTCTATACATTAAGTTAATAACTTGACATATGGTGGTCTTACTGGCATATAGTAGTTCTCTTTTTCTCTTTGTGTTCTCAGGCCCGCATAACTGATACCTGCCTACTCAATGAAACTGAGCCTACGTTCAAATGGTTAACCTTACATAATTGATATGGTATTATTTAGTTAATGCTTGTTAGACATATATTTTTATAAAAATTCACGACAGTAATTTTAAACCTAAACACTATAAACTATAATTTTTTAAGTTAAACCCCCCTACCCCCCGTTAAACTAACACCTAGTATGAATGGCCACTTATTTCTCGTCAAACCCCTAAATCCGAGAGCGACCAAACAGCATAAGCGTTAGTTATACAAATATCCTGAATATTTGTATTATATTAAATACACGCTACATTACCACAAACTTTTACCAAAAGTAATACACAAACAAATTTTATCCTACTTTACTAAACCCGCATAAACATTACACGCTTTAAATACTACTATATAAAAGACAAATAAAAATTTACCTTAATATAAAACACTGCAAAGCCACTAAATAAAATTAAAACTACTCAAAAATACAAACACAAGTAATAAACTCCAAAAACTCCCACCCACAACAATATACTCAACATATACCGCATACCAACACCTCTATTTAAACCTACCAAACACACCCCAGAAACTCAAAACATCACAAAGACTAGACCATCTAGTTTCCATAGAAAAATAGGTCTTGAACCTATACCAGAGAGATCAAAACTCCCCATACTTCCATTATACTACATCCTAGTAAAGTCAGCTAATTAAGCTCTTGGGCCCATACCCCAAAAATGTCGGTTAAAATCCTTCCTTTACTAATGAACCCACACGCAAGCATAATTATTACTTTAAGCCTAATTATAGGACCCCTAATCACCATCTCTAGTAATCATTGAATCCTAGCATGAACCGGATTAGAAATCAGCACCTTAGCTATTACCCCATTAATCGCCAAACAACACCACCCACGAGCAATTGAAGCCACCATTAAATACTTCCTGACACAAGCAACCGCCTCAACACTAATTCTATCCTCTAGCATTATTAATGCCTGAACACTGGGCCAATGAGACATCACACAAATGTCTAACAACACTTCATGCGCAATTCTAACCACAGCCCTAGCCATTAAATTAGGACTAGCACCCTTCCACTTCTGATTGCCAGAAGTCCTACAAGGAACTTCCACAACAACAGCCTTAATCCTAACTACCTGACAAAAATTAGCTCCTCTATCCCTACTAGTAATAACCACCCAATCCCTAAACACACCATTACTACTATTATTAGGATTAATATCCACCTTAGTTGGCGGATGGGGCGGACTAAACCAACCCCAACTACGAAAAATCATAGCATTCTCCTCCATCGCTCACCTAGGGTGAATAATTACAATCATTACTTTCTCACCTAAACTTATATTACTCACATTCTACACATACATTACTATAACTACAGCCATATTCCTCATAATTAAACTCCTAGAGACAAACAAAATCTCTATAATAATAACATCATGGACAAAACTACCAACACTAAACACCATCATAATTCTAATCCTTATGTCACTAGCCGGACTACCACCACTAACAGGGTTCATGCCCAAATGATTAATTCTTCAAGAACTAACCAAACAGCACATATTCATTATCGCCACCATAATAGCTCTACTCTCACTACTCAGCTTATTCTTCTACTTACGAATCTCATACTGCGCAACCATTACATTACCCCCAAACTCAACTAACTATTTACAACAATGACGTCACAAAACTAACCAAAAACCCTACCTAGCTCCAATAGCCACACTATCTATCACCCTGCTCCCTATCACACCTACCCTACTAACCCTCCTCTAGAAACTTAGGATCAAGCCAATTTTTAAACCGGGGGCCTTCAAAGCCCCAAAAAAGAGATAGAACCTCTTAGTTTCTGTTAAGACCTATAGGGCTCTATCCTATATCTTATGAATGCAACTCAGACACTTTAATTAAGCTAAAGTCTCACTAGACAAATGGGCCTCGATCCCATAAAAATTTAGTTAACAGCTAAACACCCAAATCCAGCGGGCTTTTATCTAATTTTCCCGCTCTCAGAAAAAGCGGGAAAACCCCGACACAAATCAAAGTGTATCTCCGAATTTGCAATTCGGAATGAATTTCACTACGAGGTTTGATAAGAAGAGGGGTTAAACCTCTATAAAAAGGTCTACAGCCTAACGCTTAAGCACTCAGCCATCTTACCTATGATTTTAACCCGCTGATTTTTTTCTACTAACCATAAAGACATTGGTACCTTATACCTTATTTTCGGGGCCTGATCAGGTATAATTGGCACAGCATTAAGTCTTTTGATCCGTGCCGAACTGAGCCAGCCAGGTACACTTCTTGGGGATGATCAGATCTACAATGTTATTGTTACGGCCCACGCTTTTGTTATAATCTTTTTCATAGTCATACCTGTTATGATCGGCGGGTTCGGAAACTGATTAGTTCCTTTAATAATTGGGGCGCCAGACATAGCATTCCCTCGTATAAACAATATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCTCCATCTCTACTGCTACTATTAATATCCTCTGGAATTGAAGCAGGTGCAGGTACCGGCTGAACTGTATACCCCCCACTAGCTGGGAATATGGCCCATTCCGGGGCCTCGGTAGACTTGACTATCTTTTCCCTTCACCTCGCCGGGGTGTCTTCAATCTTGGGGGCTATTAATTTTATCACCACAGCAATCAATATAAAATCTACAACCATGTCGCAGTACCAGACACCCCTATTCGTATGATCTGTACTCATTACAGCTATCTTATTACTACTCTCTTTACCTGTACTCGCCGCAGGGATCACTATATTACTTACAGACCGAAATCTGAATACAACTTTTTTTGACCCTTCAGGAGGGGGAGACCCCATCCTATACCAACACCTATTCTGATTCTTTGGTCACCCAGAAGTATACATTCTTATCCTACCTGGGTTTGGGATAATCTCACACATTGTAACCTGCTACGCAGGTAAAAAAGAACCATTTGGATATATAGGGATAGTGTGAGCAATAATATCCATTGGATTCCTGGGCTTTATTGTGTGAGCTCACCATATATTTACCGTTGGAATAGACGTAGACACCCGAGCCTATTTCACATCTGCAACAATAATTATTGCTATCCCAACAGGGGTAAAAGTATTTAGCTGATTAGCTACCTTGCATGGGGGAACAATCCAATGGGGGGCCGCCATAATATGGGCCCTAGGTTTCATTTTCCTATTCACCATCGGCGGACTAACAGGCATTGTACTGGCTAATTCATCTCTGGATATTGTACTCCATGATACTTACTATGTAGTAGCACACTTCCACTATGTTCTTTCAATAGGGGCCGTATTCGCCATTATAGCAGGATTTACCCATTGATTCACATTATTTACAGGATATCTATTACACCAAACCTGAACAAAAGTACACTTCGGATTAATATTTGCAGGCGTTAACATAACCTTCTTCCCTCAGCACTTCCTAGGCCTGGCAGGAATACCACGACGTTACTCTGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCCTATGAAATTCAATTTCGTCAATCGGATCATTAATTTCTCTAGTAGCAGTAATTATAATAATATTTATTATCTGAGAAGCATTTTGTTCAAAGCGTAAAATAGTATTAACTGAACTCAAAACTACAAACGTAGAGTGACTACACGGTTGCCCACCACCATACCACACTTATGAAGAACCAGCCCACATGCAAGTTCAAGAAAGGAGGGAATTGAACCCCCTTAAATTAGTTTCAAGCCAACTACATAACCTTTATGCTACCTTCTTCTAAAGACGTTAGTAAAATATATTACTAAACCTTGTCAAGGTTAAATTATAAGTGAAACCCCTATACGCCTTAATGGCCCACCCGCTGCAACTAGGATTCCAGGACGCAATATCACCCGTTATAGAAGAACTCCTTCACTTTCATGACCATACCCTAATAATTGTATTTTTAATCAGCACCTTAGTGCTCTACATCATTACACTAATAATAACAACAAAACTAACATACACTAACACTATAAATGCTCAAGAAGTGGAAATAATTTGAACTATTCTACCAGCAATTGTCCTAATCACCATTGCACTCCCCTCCCTACGAGTCTTGTACTTAATAGATGAAATTAATAACCCGCATTTAACAATTAAAACCATAGGACATCAATGATACTGAACGTACGAGTATACTGACTACGAAAACCTTGAGTTTGACTCTTACATGATCCATGCCCAAGATCTACCAAACGGGTACTTTCGATTATTAGAAGTAGACCACCGCATGGTCATACCAATAGAATCGCCAATCCGAATTCTAATCTCGGCTGAAGACGTCCTACACTCATGAGCAATCCCATCATTAGGTGTAAAAACAGACGCAGTGCCCGGACGATTGAACCAAACAACTTTCATTATTACACGACCAGGAATATTCTACGGACAATGTTCAGAAATCTGCGGGGCTAACCATAGCTTCATGCCAATTGTGGTAGAATCTGTGCCACTACAATACTTCGAAAACTGATCTTCACTAATACTCTCCTAACCACTATAGAAGCTAAACAGGATAGCGCTAGCCTTTTAAACTAGAGAAAGAGAATTCCCCACCCTCCTTAGTGACATGCCACAACTAAATCCAGACCCTTGATTCTTAATTCTGTCTCTCGCATGATTAACCTACATTCTCGTCCTACAACCAAAAATTCTATCCAACAAGTCTATAAATCACCCAACCAACAAAAACAACGAAATTATTAAAACAAACCCATGAACATGACCATGACCCTAACCATAAACCTAACATTTTTTAATCAATTCACAAGCCCGCAAATCATAGGAGTTCCATTAATTATACTCGCTCTATTAGCACCATCAGCCATGTTCCAAACCCAAAACAACCGATGGTTAACTAACCGTCTTTCATTACTCCAATTATGAATAATTAACCTATTCACAAAACAACTAATATCGCCCATTAGTAAAACAGGACATCAGTGATCCGTTATCTTAACATCACTAATAATTATACTCTTAATAATTAATCTGCTAGGACTTCTACCATATACATTCACCCCTACAACACAACTCTCCATAAATATAGGACTAGCCATCCCAATATGATTAGCCACAGTACTAACAGGCCTTCGAAACCAACCAACTGCATCACTAGGACACCTTCTACCAGAAGGGACCCCAAACCTATTAACCCCAATCCTCATCATCATTGAAACTATTAGCCTTTTTATCCGACCATTAGCCCTAGGTGTACGACTTACAGCCAATCTTACAGCTGGCCACCTATTAATTCAACTTACTTCTACCGCAACATTTGCTTTACTCCCAACAATACCAACCTTATCTATGCTAACCATAGTTGTACTATTATTATTATCTATTCTAGAACTAGCAGTAGCAATAATTCAAGCCTACGTCTTCGTCTTATTACTAAGCCTCTACCTTCAAGAAAACACCTAATGACCCACCAAACTCATGCCTACCACATAGTAGACCCTAGCCCATGACCATTAACAGGCGCAGCAGCATCATTACTAATAACCTCTGGGTTCGCCATGTGATTTCACCATAACTCAATACTACTAATAACCCTAGGTTTATTAACTATACTACTGACTATACTCCAGTGATGACGAGACATTGTTCGAGAAGGAACCTTCCAAGGCCATCACACCACTCCAGTACAGAAAAGCCTACGATACGGTATAATCCTATTCGTCACGTCAGAAGTATTCTTTTTTATTGGATTCTTCTGAGCTTTCTACCACTCAAGCCTGTCCCCCACACCAGAATTAGGGGGATGTTGACCACCAACAGGAATTTCTCCACTAAATCCATTTGAAGTACCACTGTTGAATACAGCAGTCTTACTGGCCTCAGGGGTAACAATTACCTGAGCCCACCATAGCCTGATAGAAGTCAACCGACACCAGACTATCCAAGCCCTTATATTAACAGTTTTACTAGGTTTGTACTTCACAACCCTACAAGCCCTGGAGTACTACGAAGCCCCGTTTACAGTTGCTGACGGTGTGTACGGCTCTACATTTTTTATTGCAACAGGCTTTCACGGACTCCACGTAATTATTGGATCAACATTTCTAATCGTATGCCTGATACGGCAAATAAAATTCCACTTCACCTCCGCCCATCACTTCGGATTCGAAGCATCCGCTTGATACTGACACTTTGTAGATGTTGTATGACTATTCCTTTATGTATCAATCTACTGATGAGGCTCATACTCTTCTAGTACAAAATAGTACCAGTGACTTCCAATCACTAAATTTTAGCTATACCCTAAAGAAGAGTAATGAACGTAACAATCTCCATTATAACAATCGCCCTCATCCTATCAGTAGTTTTAATAACACTGAACTATTGATTAACACTAGTAAAACCAAACAACGAAAAACTATCCCCATACGAATGCGGCTTCGATCCATTAGAATCAGCTCGTTTACCATTCTCAATCCAATTTTTTCTCAGTAGCAATCTTATTCTTACTATTTGATTTAGAAATCGCATTACTCTTACCTCTACCATGAGCTATTCAACTGTTATCACCAACCTACACCTTCACCTGAGCACTTATAATCCTACTACTTCTAACATTGGGCCTCATTTATGAATGAGTTCAAGGGGGCTTGGAATGGGCAGAATTGATAACTAGTCTAACACAAGACAACTAATTTCGACTTAGTTAATCATGATTAAATCCATGGTTATCCAATGACACCATTACATTTTAGCTATCTCTCTGCTTTTATTGTTAGCATCATAGGCCTCTCACTACATCGAACCTACCTTATCTCCACCCTATTATGCTTAGAAAGCATAATATTATCCATATTTATTGCCCTATCAATATGACCTATCCAACTACAAACTTCATCATTTATACTCACTCCCATACTAATACTATCCTTCTCAGCCTGCGAAGCAGGCACCGGCCTATCCTTACTTGTGGCATCCTCACGAACCCATGGTTCAGACCACTTACAAAACTTAAACCTATTACAATGCTAAAAATCATACTTCCAACCATTATATTATTACCCACAACTATGCTCTGCAAACCAAAACAACTATGAATCACTATATTAACCCATAGTTTTGGGATTGCCTTTTTAAGCCTACAGTGATTTAAACCCTCCATGGAATTTACAAGCTTCTCCAACCATTACTTAGGGGTAGACCAAATTTCAGCCCCATTACTCATCTTAACATGCTGACTCAGCCCACTAATAGTCCTGGCCAGTCAAAACCACTTGACTAAAGAACCAGTTACACGAAAACGAACCTTTATCTCCACTATTATTCTACTACAAACCTCATTAATCCTGGCCTTCTCTGCCACAGAACTAATCATATTCTTCATAGCATTTGAAGCTACACTGATTCCAACACTAGTAATTATTACACGCTGAGGAAACCAAATAGAACGGCTAAATGCTGGAACCTATTTCCTATTCTACACTCTTATTGGATCCCTCCCCCTACTAATTGCCCTCCTTTCACTTCATACCCAAAATGGAACCCTATCCCTCTGTACTATTCAACTCAACCAACACGCCATATTAAATTCATGAACCCACACAACATGATGATTTGCATTACTAACAGCCTTCATAATCAAAATACCATTGTATGGGCTACATCTATGACTACCAAAAGCACACGTAGAAGCTCCAATCGCAGGGTCAATAATCCTAGCAGCTGTACTTCTCAAACTCGGGGGGTATGGCATTATCCGTATTATAATAACTCTAGATCCTTTATCAAAAACACTCTCTTATCCATTTATAGTCCTAGCTCTATGGGGAGTAGTCATAACCAGTTCAATCTGCTTACACCAAACAGACCTAAAATCACTAATCGCTTACTCATCAGTAAGTCACATAGGACTAGTCACTGCCGCAGCACTAACCCAAACCCACTGAGCCCATACTGGAGCAATCACACTCATAATCGCCCACGGTCTAACATCATCAATACTCTTTTGCCTAGCAAACACAAACTATGAGCGAACCCACAACCGAACATTATTAATTGCCCGAAATATGCAACTATTCCTGCCACTAATGGGGACATGATGACTACTTGCCAGCCTAGCAAACATAGCCATCCCACCGACGATTAACTTAATAGGAGAACTAACTATTATTGCCTCATTATTCAACTGATCCAACATTACAATCCTAATAACAGGGTTAGGAACTTTACTCACTGCTACCTACACCTTACATATACTATCTACAACACAATGAGGAAAGACACCCTCATATATTAAAACTATCCCTCCAACTCACACACGAGAACATTTACTGATGGCACTCCACACTATACCCATAGCACTATTAATAGTAAAACCAGAACTAATCTGAGGGGCCTTTCACTGTACTATATTCCTAAAATAAATATTAGATATAGGAGTTTAAATCTCCTTATAGACCCAAAAGTAATAAAAACTCACCCAATATTTAAAACCACCTTTCCCCACTCCCAAAAAGAGAAAAAACCTAATGTTTCAAAACTATCAATGCAATTCCAAGTAATACCGCACCCATAGCCTTAGCCTAACATTACTTACCCTAATACTACCGTATATAATACTCTCCATTTAAGCATAAAACAACACCTTCCACAATCCTGACACAACTCTTTACATCTATAAACACTGAACTTATCATACTTAACCCAAAATTACCTACTACATCACGCACAAACACACACTACTTTAAACTAACCCCCACTACCTCACATAACACACCACCCTACACCCTATCAGATTCACTTTAAAATTTTTCATCTCCACACAACCTAAACGATTAGAAACTCACCAAACACCTATTAATAGCCCTAATAATAACTAATAATTTAATTTTTTTAAATAATAGACAAAAATCACATTACTACTTATAATTGAACAATAACAAAGCTGACCAAACAACTTACTACAACCTCACACATACCCATTAAGAACTTACCTGCCTTCCTTACCCAATCTTACACTTCTTCACAGTACTCTAATCGCACGAAGCACTCCACGAGACAAACCACGAACCAATTCCAACACAACAAACAATGTTAACAATAGCCCTCAACCAGCAATCAAAAAAATTACATTGCCCAAATAATAAAATCATGACACTCCACTAAAATCCAGCCGAACCACACATAATCCACCAGCATCAACTGTGATATGACCAAACCCTTCGGTACCCCACAACCAATGACCAATAACTACAAGTCCAATAATAACTAAAACATAAACCACCATATACACCACCCCCCACAAACTCCCTCAACCAATAGGATATGGCTCCGCAACTAATGCAGCCGAATAAGCAAAAATTACCAATATCCCTCCCAAATAAATTAAAAACAACACTAAAGAAACAAAAGACCCCCCAACACTTACCAACACCCCACACCCAGAAGCCGCACCCAGGATTAAACTTAAAACTCCGTAATAAGGCGACGGATTACAAGACACACCCACCATTCAAAAAACAAAACAAAACCCAAATAAAAATATAAAATATATCATAATTCTTGCATGGACTTTAACCAAGACTAATGATCTGAAAAACCACTGTTGTATTCAACTACAAAAACCTAATGACCACAAATACACGAAAAACCCACCCTATAATAAAAATTATCAACAACTCATTCATTGACCTACCAAGCCCGTCTAATATCTCTGCTTGATGAAACTTCGGATCACTACTAGGTATCTGCCTAATTTTACAAATTATCACTGGAATTTTCCTAGCAATACACTACTCACCAGACGTCTCCCTGGCATTTTCATCAATTACACACATCTCTCGAGATGTACAATACGGATGACTTATTCGCAACATACACGCTAATGGTGCCTCCTTATTCTTCATGTACATCTATATCCACATCGGACGAGGACTATACTACGGCTCATACTTGTACAAAGAGACATGAAACACAGGGATCATTCTTCTACTACTAACTATAGCCACCGCGTTCGTAGGTTATGTTCTCCCATGGGGCCAAATATCATTCTGAGGCGCTACTGTAATCACCAACCTACTCTCAGCTATTCCATATATGGGCAGCACATTAGTACAGTGGATTTGAGGGGGGTTTTCAGTGGACAACGCAACCTTAACCCGATTCTTTACCTTCCATTTTCTTTTACCATTCATTACTTCCGGCTTCGCAATAGTACATCTTCTATTTCTGCATGAGACAGGATCAAACAACCCAACAGGATTAAACTCAAACACTGATAAAATCCCCTTCCACCCGTACTTTTCATATAAAGACTTACTAGGAATTATCCTAACACTAGCCTTACTACTAACCCTCGCACTATTCTCCCCAAATCTTTTAGGAGACCCTGACAACTTTACACCAGCCAACCCTCTATCCACTCCTCCCCATATTAAACCAGAATGATACTTCCTCTTCGCTTATGCAATCCTACGATCAATTCCTAACAAACTAGGTGGCGTACTTGCCCTCCTATTAGCTATCCTTATATTACTCCTAATACCTATCCTACATACATCAAAACAACGAACCACATCATTCCGACCACTAACCCAAATCCTCTTCTGATTCTTAGTTGCTGACCTATTAGTACTAACGTGAATCGGGGGACAGCCAGTTGAAGCCCCGTTCACCGCCATCAGCCAAATAGCCTCTATCCTATACTTCTTAATCCCATTAATCTTAATGCCTACCACAGGCGTAATCGAAAACAAAATACTAAACCTAAAATACTCTAGTAGCACACCCCACTAAAGCACTGGCCATAAACCAAAGACTGAAGACTATAATCTTCCTAGAGTAATCAAAAGAGAAGGACTTAAACCTCCATTCCCGGCCCCCAAAATCGAAATCTTTTATTAAACTATATTTTGACCCCCCCCCCCCCCGATGGGCATGCTCATCGAATTTTGCCTAAATATAGGACAATTTACACCCTATGTACGTCGTGCATACTTTTATTTACCCCTAGCATATATTTAGTAATATCCCTGCTTAATCTTACATAAAAGTATATTCCCCATAATCTATCCAGATAACAGTAATTTAATGGTTTAAGGACATAATATTCTATAGTGCTTTACAACATGACTATTGTCACAGTATTGGGTTATTTCCTAATCTACCTAATCACGAGAGATAAGCAACCCTTGTTTGTAAGATACAACGTTACCAGTTTCAGGCCCATATTCATGATGGCGTACATAACTGATCTATTCTGGCCACTGGCTGTTTTTTCAGGCACATGTTATCCACTAAGTTCATTCGTTCCTCTTTAAAAGGCCTCTGGTTAAATGAGTTCTATACATTAAGTTAATAACTTGACATATGGTGGTCTTACTGGCATATAGTAGTTCTCTTTTTCTCTTTGTGTTCTCAGGCCCGCATAACTGATACCTGCCTACTCAATGAAACTGAGCCTACGTTCAAATGGTTAACCTTACATAATTGATATGGTATTATTTAGTTAATGCTTGTTAGACATATATTTTTATAAAAATTCACGACAGTAATTTTAAACCTAAACACTATAAACTATAATTTTTTAAGTTAAACCCCCCTACCCCCCGTTAAACTAACACCTAGTATGAATGGCCACTTATTTCTCGTCAAACCCCTAAATCCGAGAGCGACCAAACAGCATAAGCGTTAGTTATACAAATATCCTGAATATTTGTATTAATGTTACAGCAATAAATTTATTATGTTATACTATGTTATAGTATAGTGTGTGTTATATAATATATGTTGTTATATAATATATGTTGTTATATAATATATGTTGTTATATAATATATGTTGTTATATAATATATGTTGTTATATAATATGTGTTGTTATATAATATGTGTTGTTATATAATATAT
```

How to get the sequence from such file??

Comment: First of all, in the code example you provided, `seq` does nothing, so it can be omitted. Second, is the program returning (IE ending) before it prints the second line, or is it hanging (IE still active, but not responding)? If its the later, then python is *trying* to print it, but that is a *massive* line. You may be better off printing it in chunks.

Comment: The lines you gave printed fine for me...

Comment: How did you determine that in the file there is a newline between `> NC_007970` and the long string? If there is just a space in between them, a text editor with soft wrapping enabled might chose to break at that space and fool you into thinking there's a newline. Your code is correct in the sense that it will print every line in a file.

Comment: @ITNinja what do you mean by print it by chunks?

Comment: @darthbith you use python 2.7?

Comment: @LukasGraf in all cases I'm not able to get the sequence line

Comment: @LukasGraf and I added new line manually still it is printing the first line only

Comment: I used the code you posted with Python 2.7 to read the sample data that you provided here. It prints both lines of the file.

Comment: @qwrrty that is strange !

Comment: What platform are you running this on: Linux, Windows, Mac or something else? Is it possible that the last line of the file is missing a trailing newline that is confusing your output?

Comment: @qwrrty windows 7 I added a new line also not working

Comment: @AWRAM Yes, Python 2.7.6. If you replace the print line with `print line,'test'`, does the text `test` print on the next line?

Comment: Thanks all for your help, the problem is from eclipse I use pydev, if I run it directly from python command line it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

AWRAM, may I suggest you check out the `BioPython` package?

Specific code I would use to do what you're trying to do would be as follows:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

file = open('NC_007970.fas', r)
for record in SeqIO.parse(file, "clustal") :
    print record.seq
file.close()
```

BioPython will parse each FASTA file as an iterator of SeqRecord objects, from which you can query for each SeqRecord's sequence, and use it to manipulate other things too.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm also a fellow biologist dealing with virus sequences, and the BioPython package is immensely useful for that.

Comment: I was using it and it gives the same problem here which is the length of the sequence... the code above prints nothing and print record alone gives (ID: NC_007970
Name: NC_007970
Description:  NC_007970
Number of features: 0
Seq('GTTATTGTAGCTTACACTAAAGCATGGCACTGAAGTTGCCAAGATGGGTAATCA...TAT', SingleLetterAlphabet())

Comment: I see, AWRAM. Is there a reason why you would like to see the whole sequence? I guarantee you that even though the sequence is not printed in full to the screen (to save space), it definitely is held in full in memory.